# How can I get a google sheet that checks the a price compared to the current price and calculates a % difference based on the set ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a google sheet that compares the current price of items to the new updated price, as a percentage based on the price range. Then outputs this so I can ignore superfluous price changes.

I want to separate each price into ranges (<=100,>100 <=500, >500) and then check the price difference for each range based on whether it is greater than 10%, 5% and 1% respectively. Then output this as a check box so I can easily sort out the useful updates (I will also use this to update the current price).

Current price $10.99 new price $10.90 is a 1% price drop this would be superfluous

Current price $400 new price $420 is a 10% price rise this is useful

I don't know the syntax for it but something like:

```
newPrice/currentPrice = difference; IF( newPrice > 500);    If difference > 0.9 or < 1.1 = mark; elseIf(newPrice <= 500 and >100); If difference > 0.5 or < 1.05 = mark; elseIf(newPrice <= 100);   If difference > 0.1 or < 1.01 = mark
```

[image: This is a mock-up of the sheet]

I am wanting to compare the current price with the new price and only mark

- The prices with a change greater than 10% on values less than $100
- The prices with a change greater than 5% on vales between $100 and $500
- The prices with a change greater than 1% on vales greater than $500

So in the above example, the first entry would not be marked but the second one would.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me if you want to sort by current or new price.
I understand also that you have two enquiries 1) how to filter by price range and 2) how to filter by drop. In general:

1. If `A1` is your current price and `B1` is your new price
2. Then you can set the price difference (%) in `C1` by typing: `=(B1-A1)/A1 * 100`.
3. Then you can add something like this in `D1`:

```
=if(C1<-10,"HIGH DROP", if(C1<-5,"MEDIUM DROP", if(C1<-1,"SMALL DROP", "INCREASE OR EQUAL")))
```

This will display:

- `high drop` if the drop is greater than 10%
- `medium drop` if the drop is between 5% and 10%
- `small drop` if the drop is between 1% and 5%
- `increase or equal` if there a drop lower than 1% or if the price has increased.

4. To filter your data, you can select your column header, and click on `Data>Create Filter`.
5. You can then select the category you want to filter:

[image: filter of drop]

6. And even add condition to your price range:

[image: filter price range]

Comment: To clarify I don't want to sort the table as it is over 13k entries and I need it to stay in a set order. I am trying to compare the price on the sheet with a new update that will be a shorter list of 100 to 400 entries that I will use Vlookup to align with the correct price. I am wanting to check if the price change is noteworthy ie if it's only a few cents change it's not worth changing physical tickets when the online database has already been updated.

Comment: Ok. I suggest to replace `sort` in your question by `tag` or something like that in your question. Have you already tried `format>Conditional formatting` then?

Comment: Or may be something like this to take the previous example: `if(OR(AND(C3<-10,A3<100), AND(C3<-5,A3<500,A3>=100), AND(C3<-1,A3>=500)), "MARK", "")`

Comment: Conditional formatting would work to flag the result but because we need to do different calculations for different price ranges it's going to be much more complicated. I am hoping to get it all done in a single script. I have updated the post with what I believe the code needs to be but the syntax is definitely wrong.